# grep that match around the first match

Tags: grep, match

I would like to grep a specific word 'foo' inside specific files, then get the N lines around my match and show only the blocks that contain a second grep.

I found this but it doesn't really work...

```
find . | grep -E '.*?\.(c|asm|mac|inc)$' | \
xargs grep --color -C3 -rie 'foo' | \
xargs -n1 --delimiter='--' | grep --color -l 'bar'
```

For instance I have the file 'a':

```
a
b
c
d
bar
f
foo
g
h
i
j
bar
l
```

The file b:

```
a
bar
c
d
e
foo
g
h
i
j
k
```

I expect this for grep -c2 on both files because bar is contained in the -c2 range of foo. I do not get any match for ./bar because bar is not in the range -c2 of foo...

```
--
./foo-    bar
./foo-    f
./foo-    **foo**
./foo-    g
./foo-    h
--
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Give an example text, and what you like to get out of it.  It may be other approach to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I only understand the first line of your question and this does what I think you mean!

```
#!/bin/bash
N=2
pattern1=a
pattern2=z
matchinglines=$(awk -v p="$pattern1" '$0~p{print NR}' file)    # Generate array of matching line numbers
for x in ${matchinglines[@]}
do
   ((start=x-N))
   [[ $start -lt 1 ]] && start=1   # Avoid passing negative line nmumbers to sed
   ((end=x+N))
   echo DEBUG: Checking block between lines $start and $end
   sed -ne "${start},${end}p" file | grep -q "$pattern2"
   [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && sed -ne "${start},${end}p" file
done
```

You need to set `pattern1` and `pattern2` at the start of the script. It basically does some `awk` to build an array of the line numbers that match your first pattern. Then it loops through the array and sets the start and end range to +/-N either side of each matching line number. It then uses `sed` to extraact that block and passes it through `grep` to see if it contains `pattern2` printing it if it does. It may not be the most efficient, but it is easy enough to understand and maintain.

It assumes your file is called `file`

Answer (score 1):

You could do this pretty simply with a "while read line" loop:

> find -regextype posix-extended -regex "./file[a-z]" | while read line; do grep -nHC2 "foo" $line | grep --color bar; done

**Output:**

> ./filea-5-**bar** 
>   ./filec-46-... host pwns.me [94.23.120.252]: 451 4.7.1 Local **bar**
>   configuration error ...

In this example, I created the following files:
filea - your example a
fileb - your example b
filec - some random exim log output with foo and bar tossed in 2 lines apart
filed - the same exim log output, but with foo and bar tossed in 3 lines apart

You could also pipe the output after done, to alter the format:

> ; done | sed 's/-([0-9]{1,6})-/: line: \1 ::: /'

**Formatted output**
./filea: line: 5 ::: **bar** 
./filec: line: 46 ::: ... host pwns.me [94.23.120.252]: 451 4.7.1 Local **bar** configuration error ...

Answer (score 0):

pipe it twice

```
 grep "[^foo\n]" | grep "\n{ntimes}foo\n{ntimes}"
```